# Can we add extra column to unigrid for default cms modules in kentico

Tags: sql-server, content-management-system, kentico

[image: unigrid]

I want to add a "timezone" column to the grid shown above. The "Countries" module is under the "Configuration" section. How can I add the column? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The UniGrid definition for the Countries application is located here:

```
~/CMS/App_Data/CMSModules/Cms/UI/Grids/CMS_Country/default.xml
```

Your screenshot is showing the States tab, so the grid definition would be here:

```
~/CMS/App_Data/CMSModules/Cms/UI/Grids/CMS_State/default.xml
```

You can add columns to the grid by editing the XML grid definition files, as per [this reference](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/references/kentico-controls/ui-controls/unigrid/reference-unigrid-definition).

It would be simple to display the column if you are going to [add additional columns](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/editing-system-tables) to the `CMS.Country` class.
However, timezones in Kentico are not tied to the `CMS.Country` class.
If your timezone data is stored in a different class/table, you would need to use a [custom UniGrid transformation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/references/kentico-controls/ui-controls/unigrid/adding-custom-unigrid-transformations) or [custom extender](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/creating-extenders-for-module-interface-pages) to retrieve the data and display it.

Comment: Be aware that this approach will cause the potential upgrade procedure to complain about the modified files. Though it shouldn't hard to resolve the conflict in this case, you should consider copying the UI and making the customizations there as per [Best practices for customization](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/best-practices-for-customization).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.